# pygame and python not working for me

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just starting out with pygame and I'm have a bit of an issue, here is my code...

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

```
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

and here is the error i keep getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1521, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Python\pygame.… line 1, in <module>
import pygame, sys
File "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Python\pygame.… line 2, in <module>
from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'; pygame is not a package
```

So my question is how do i get pygame to work with python?
python version 3.3.2
pygame version: Python 3.3 pygame-1.9.2pre(64-bit)

Comment: If your python install is 32bit, then you will need the 32bit pygame installer.

Answer (score 1):

Your pygame install was no successful what you need to do is install python 2.7 from [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)

then you need to reinstall your pygame. If you are using python 3.3 you will want to make a new install with the older version it will not delete your newer one. Make sure that it says the install is sucsessful. If that doesn't work try rebooting and/or reinstalling. GOOD LUCK!!